# Angular immutable array for Select boxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

My requirement is to have multiple select boxes with same dropdowns(ng-options) array, but if I select a value in one select box it should be removed from the other select box drop down.

In the on change event I'm trying to have a new array excluding the item that was selected for first that array. But it gets removed from both the select boxes. Like a immutable DS always returns a mutated clone of original.

Need suggestion on is it possible to achieve this way or is there a way around for it

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.selectedItem = { name: 'two', id: 27 };
  $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30 },{ name: 'two', id: 27 },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
  $scope.remove=function(data){
    $scope.items=$scope.items.filter(item=>{
          return item.name!==data.name;
    });
  
});
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="remove(selectedItem)" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>


    <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>

  </body>
</html>
```

```js
 $scope.remove=function(data){
    $scope.items=$scope.items.filter(item=>{
          return item.name!==data.name;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using filter pipe in the ng-options syntax.
Have a look at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n0yTlT?p=preview)

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="item.name for item in items | filter: coolFilter1"></select>

      <select ng-model="selectedItem2" ng-options="item.name for item in items | filter: coolFilter2"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using `items` in both select boxes, changes on `items` array will reflect in both select boxes. Either use separate arrays for select boxes or find a way to filter out the items from the first select box. For example, you could set `selected=true` on a selected item in the first select box, then filter out `items` in the first select box by adding a filter `!selected` to `ng-options`. This way you can use the same `items` array on both boxes.

Answer (score 1):

When you using ES6 arrow function, you don't need to write 'return'.

```
$scope.items=$scope.items.filter(item => item.name !== data.name);
```

and this `$scope.items=$scope.items.filter` reassigning looks weird.. It will be better not to change the origin object.

You can give each object in $scope.items a boolean, then filter it out in the view.

```
ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id | filter:{'isUsed': false}"
```